# Vagrant commands failing

Tags: variables, path, initialization, vagrant

I am new to Vagrant!

I have installed Vagrant from https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.19/vagrant_2.2.19_x86_64.msi

and when i checked the version in Powershell am getting Vagrant 2.2.19. But when i am trying to add box or init am getting error.

below are the details of the error am getting

PS C:> vagrant -v
Vagrant 2.2.19

PS C:> vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.

PS C:> vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.

I have searched on internet and youtube but did not find any help....

Please help me ...... !

FYI : I have restarted my windows 10 computer after installing Vagrant

Answer (score 1):

FOUND ANSWER :

I have done two things, firstly

```
   vagrant plugin update
```

and secondly i have edited the environment variables

[This PC (rightclick) ---> Properties ----> Advanced system settings ----> Under Advanced Tab Select Environment Variables]

In the Environment Variables window Under System variables select PATH and click on Edit ----> Click on New and add
the Powershell bin path C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

After this i have restarted my powershell thats it.....Vagrant commands started working.

Comment: if any one is using git bash and facing the same error we can add the git bash path in the environment variables then Vagrant command will work in git bash too. I have added this  C:\Program Files\Git\bin  in environment variables to PATH

Answer (score 0):

hello，i just solved this problem ,you can remove the 'cmd.exe'from the PATH ,so you should see the cmd.exe's path like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1I7q.png)

after this ,type 'vagrant' in your powershell ,it will run success.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).